# Availability of derivative for multivariable functions: Are these conditions equivalent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In Hubbard's multivariable calculus book a function $f:\mathbb R^m \mapsto \mathbb R^n$ has a derivative at a point $a \in \mathbb R^m$ if the following equation holds:

$$\lim_{\vec h \to \vec 0}\frac{1}{||\vec h||}\left( (f(a+\vec h)-f(a))-[Df(a)]\vec h) \right)=\vec 0$$

But in one example this equation is used without explanation:

$$\lim_{\vec h \to \vec 0}\frac{1}{||\vec h||}|| (f(a+\vec h)-f(a))-[Df(a)]\vec h) ||= 0$$

They seem to represent exactly the same thing but I don't want to come to a conclusion on my own. Are these conditions equivalent?

Comment: A  vector  has  norm  $0$  iff  it  is  the  $0$  vector. Does  this  help?

Comment: @user118494 I am aware of this fact but my real concern is about the directions of $\vec h$. When we use a norm it can never be negative but different directions may give a negative derivative. Doesn't this limit the usage of this condition?

Comment: @user118494 I mean I suspect some limitations in the second equation.

Comment: I  thought  total  derivative  would  be  same  at  a  point  of  differentiability    irrespective  of  the  direction  of  the  vector  $h$ .  But  correct  me  if  I  am  wrong . I  am  no  expert  in  several  variables,actually  studying   it  recently .

Comment: @user118494 I am also learning so I may misunderstand you. But here, the derivative $[Df(a)]$ is a matrix which is used to find the directional derivatives. So $[Df(a)]\vec h$ should be different for different directions of $\vec h$.

Comment: The forward direction of the equivalence is just a special case of the more general fact that you can pass limits through continuous functions: If $f(h)\to x$, then $g(f(h))\to g(x)$ if $g$ is continuous. In your case, $g$ is the norm function, which is obviously continuous. The reverse direction depends on user118494's first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this directly follows from the definition of limits in normed vector spaces. Let's start with a simple example: Let $X$ a normed vector space with norm $\vert\vert\cdot \vert\vert$ and $(x_n)_{n\geq0}, x \in X$ then:

$$ x_n \to x, \; n\to \infty  $$
$$\Leftrightarrow x_n - x\to 0, \; n\to \infty  $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon>0 \; \exists \; N\geq 0: \vert\vert x_n - x \vert \vert < \varepsilon \; \forall n\geq N $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \vert\vert x_n - x \vert \vert \to 0, \; n \to \infty $$

Notice that the final limit is a limit in $\mathbb R$. Similarly we can always prove the limit of a function $g: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ in terms of the limit of a function $\widetilde{g}: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$. In your case:

$$\lim_{\vec h \to \vec 0}\frac{1}{||\vec h||}\left( (f(a+\vec h)-f(a))-[Df(a)]\vec h) \right)=\vec 0$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon>0 \; \exists \; \delta >0: \big\vert\big\vert\frac{1}{||\vec h||}\left( (f(a+\vec h)-f(a))-[Df(a)]\vec h) \right)\big\vert\big\vert <\varepsilon \; \forall \vec h \text{ with }\vert\vert \vec h \vert\vert < \delta  $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \lim_{\vec h \to \vec 0}\big\vert\big\vert\frac{1}{||\vec h||}\left( (f(a+\vec h)-f(a))-[Df(a)]\vec h) \right)\big\vert\big\vert=0$$

Comment: Sir, this answer of yours is very much enlightening. Thank you very much.